# C# - Advanced foreach statements?

Tags: c#, foreach

I currently have:

```
string settings = "setting1:value1;setting2:value2";
string[] pair;
foreach(string setting in settings.Split(';'))
{
    pair = setting.Split(':');
    MessageBox.Show(pair[0] + ":" + pair[1]);
}
```

I would something more along the lines of:

```
string settings = "setting1:value1;setting2:value2";
foreach (string[] pair in string setting.Split(':') in settings.Split(';'))
{
    MessageBox.Show(pair[0] + ":" + pair[1]);
}
```

The two `in` keywords seem a bit ridiculous, but I would think something like this would be possible and very easy, I just don't know how.

So, is it possible?

Comment: The second form would be much less readable anyway, in part because there's only one `pair` for each `setting`. Your current code is fine. :)

Comment: My LINQ-fu is a bit rusty, but I do believe you want to use `SelectMany` to accomplish this.

Comment: For the sake of saving 1 line of code??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure this is more readable, but you asked for it and I think it looks cool ;-)

```
string settings = "setting1:value1;setting2:value2";
foreach(var pair in settings.Split(';').Select(str => str.Split(':')))
{
    MessageBox.Show(pair[0] + ":" + pair[1]);
}
```

(I haven't compiled it, so I'm sorry if there are syntax errors)

Comment: +1 for acknowledging that it's not necessarily more readable, and because LINQ is cool.

Comment: Thanks, after opening this question I did a little research too and found the lambda, which you used. I'm still a bit confused, even after reading some articles and seeing code examples, about how it works.

Comment: @Walkerneo All it does is run an anonymous method on each member of the collection. The method gets a string as a parameter, splits it and returns a collection. The lambda expression is equivalent to a method whose body is `{ return param.Split(':'); }`. The `Select` method makes sure that the lambda is run for every member of the collection, and returns an `IEnumerable<>`.

Comment: Alright, awesome. Performance-wise, is this terrible, or better?

Comment: @Walkerneo - the string array returned from calling `Split` on the string is projected into an `IEnumerable<string[]>` using the LINQ `.Select()` method. The lambda passed to the `.Select()` defines what should be performed on each element in the collection that `Select()` is called on. In this case, the lambda takes a string parameter (the type is inferred from the usage) and calls `Split()` on it and implicitly returns the resulting `string[]`. Since this is being performed on a `string[]` array, the projection will return an `IEnumerable<string[]>` when the collection is enumerated.

Comment: If performance is crucial, the better way is to parse the entire string in one iteration, look for either a `:` or a `;` and manually create a collection of keys and values. But this will make the code a lot longer and probably less readable (for experienced C# programmers). I don't think there is much difference in performance between your original code and the code with the lambda expression. After all, it seems to me that the calls to `Split` are the most time-consuming operations here.

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative to the other posted answers, you can also use the LINQ syntax:

```
string settings = "setting1:value1;setting2:value2";
foreach(string[] pair in
    from setting in settings.Split(';')
    select setting.Split(':'))
{
    MessageBox.Show(pair[0] + ":" + pair[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (string[] pair in settings.Split(';').Select(setting => setting.Split(':')))
{
   MessageBox.Show(pair[0] + ":" + pair[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (string settingstr in settings.Split(';'))
{
    string[] setval = settingstr.Split(':');
    string setting = setval[0];
    string val = setval[1];
}
```

Comment: Isn't that essentially what Walkerneo has in his first example?